# Research Funding distribution across discliplines

Tags: funding

Just curious: how does research funding distributions across different disciplines in EU and US? I would like to see a more detailed chart where different physical sciences and biological sciences are listed. Thanks!

Comment: This question is not so straightforward to answer.  What counts?  In the US, funding is not only provided by the a large number of federal government agencies, but also by state and local governments, various nonprofit foundations, private individuals who want to use some of their fortune to advance knowledge, private companies, sometimes because they think they can profit from the knowledge, sometimes altruistically, sometimes to introduce bias into the journal literature.

Comment: That's the point. What are all the possible funding sources? It is also unclear to me, and it what I would like to learn.

Comment: One can list the major ongoing sources in a particular field, but how do you list Jim-Bob Bachelor Small Businessman who just died and left his entire fortune of $2 million for research on Plutarch because that was his favorite course in college 50 years ago?  People in the US do that sort of thing.  (And Classics is so underfunded that $2 million would be significant.)

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, the EPSRC (Engineering & Physical Sciences Research Council) has a handy [visualisation](https://www.epsrc.ac.uk/research/ourportfolio/vop/pack/RESEARCHAREA/) on their website to see the current funding distribution within their remit.

A similar [visualisation](http://clients.stefaner.eu/uberresearch/uk/) has been created for the BBSRC (Biotechnology and Biological Sciences Research Council) - also UK. Although this only appears to be for projects active in 2012.

[UberResearch](http://www.uberresearch.com/) compiles data on research funding, however, their service is not freely available. They do have some [samples](http://www.uberresearch.com/visual-portfolios/), which my be interesting. They appear to have data from the UK, US and EU. I've never used this service so cannot comment on its usefulness.

Most of the public funding bodies provide data on funded projects on their websites. However, it would require a lot of processing to make visualisations of it.